# Why does Chrome show nothing but div tags when I view the dom elements for an Ext JS app?

Tags: html, google-chrome, debugging, extjs, extjs6

I thought some of the Ext JS objects would translate directly into non-div html tags. Why is everything a `<div>` in element view when viewing my app in debug mode?  I never see any `<button>`,`<img>`,`<a>` or any other usual html tag.

For clarification:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your question, as it stands isn't really clear. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is for example how the textfield looks like. Inside of all divs, tables, etc. there is input component. Use a "magnifier" tool to fined precise a component that you are interested in.
What is actual the question or problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually all this divs are wrappers for positioning and styling. To see initial components go deeper in divs. Actually it's nothing to do with chrome. Moreover there is some error in console, it can also be the reason why component wasn't rendered completely.

Comment: That's the thing though--when I keep drilling down into the div's I see nothing but more divs.  And there aren't any errors in the console. I'm not sure what's going on.